# CDialog::DoModal crashes silently after migration from 32 to 64bit

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mfc

In a process to migrated an existing 32 bit MFC Code to 64 bit, I did a successful build and tried to test the code

Unfortunately while testing the process seems to fail (rather crash) in

**Failing Stack**

```
hWnd = ::CreateDialogIndirect(hInst, lpDialogTemplate,  pParentWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), AfxDlgProc);
CreateDlgIndirect(lpDialogTemplate, CWnd::FromHandle(hWndParent), hInst)
CDialog::DoModal()
```

No Dump is generated nor the generated exception is getting caught by SEH

I tried comparing the debug run with an existing working Win32 debug run but could not find any significant differences

At this moment I am clueless how I should proceed. Any sort of help is highly anticipated

**Exception Info:**
    First-chance exception at 0x000007fefd89a5ed (KernelBase.dll) in xyz.exe: 0x00001234: 0x1234.

**Actual Problem**

The Actual Problem was due to pointer truncation that was happening causing it to crash. @OwenWengered's solution did help me to pinpoint the issue and to deal with all such pointer truncation which I am currently working. Which me luck :-)

Comment: So the 32 bit codes works, right ? Where did the code fail ? In CDialog::DoModal() ? BTW: a call to CDialog::DoModal seems strange. Post some more code arround the 3 lines of code you have posted. Did you get any warnings from the 64 bit compiler ? Try recompile with all warnigns enabled.

Comment: This is the one thing that can fail when you convert 32-bit code to 64 bits.  Typically caused by storing a pointer into an int or long.  You will need to debug it.

Comment: Saying that your application crashes in DoModal() is not helpful in determining the cause. It's like saying your application crashes in main(). Set a breakpoint on the exception so you can see the local call stack at the point where the exception occurs. This is a bit old, for VS 2008, but it may help: http://otb.manusoft.com/2008/05/debugging-objectarx-break-on-exception.htm

Comment: @OwenWengerd: The Problem was due to Pointer Truncation while porting as suggested by Hans Passant. Your link did help me to identify the issue

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you. Your Psychic Power is awesome

Answer (score 0):

Just as HansPassant already said in the comments, there's little you can do other than debugging it and tracing what actually the application tried to do at that time.

For complete start, the "0x1234" value seems very odd. If you have sources, find the offending line and set breakpoint there. Then, once hit, check which of the values (hinst? lpdialogtemplate? pParentWnd?) might have been trimmed to that 0x1234. It is possible that in your debug session the value 1234 will be different, so be careful and check any pointers that look odd, ie. are too small or seem unaligned.

If you have sources, post the relevant parts around (before!) that call you quoted.

If you don't have any sources, try to get them :)

If you can't get them, then you can debug in raw (dis)assembly, but then, you'd need to quote not only the asm parts, but also register and stack values.. and well, it will be hard to get audience probabaly.

It's hard to say anything more, as currently I/we know even less about your case than you :)

Comment: I understand your point. I was just trying to gather the collective experience to get some hint's. Regarding the source, I do have it, but its propitiatory so I would have to be careful while sharing it :-). I will again switch back to my debugger and report any update I have

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar issue.  Along time ago when coding in VS6 you were able to create a manifest file (under resources) to change the look of your dialogs to give them an WinXP dialog look (with rounded edges).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289524%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

So I had a file called IDR_WIN_XP_THEME under RT_MANIFEST in Resources.

I was able to upgrade to all versions of Visual Studio.  But when I converted the app to 64 bits in VS2015 and tried to open the application in 64 bits it failed with an exception error.

Exception thrown at 0x000007FEFC94965D (KernelBase.dll)

I just deleted the IDR_WIN_XP_THEME manifest file and it started working.